# Bootstrap validation conflicts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-cli

I am using Vue.js and Bootstrap to design a website. I have a form that I am trying to run my custom validation on. It works fine until the user clicks submit which adds the `was-validated` class to the form per the bootstrap documentation.

At this point any required input field that has any input whether it meets my custom validation or not is marked as valid and gets a green border and check mark. My custom validation is still being run and displaying `b-form-invalid-feedback` correctly. However, it seems that `was-validated` is marking fields with the required prop as valid while not taking my custom validation into account this is leading to conflicting validation as a field has a green check mark (because it satisfies the required property) but still an error message because it is not yet valid per my custom validation.

I have tried removing the `:valid` style this isn't the effect I want as I do want it to display those styles when it is valid per my validation. Hope this makes sense if not I will provide pictures. I also have a second issue I have a date picker that is not displaying `b-form-invalid-feedback` at all even when `was-validated` is added.

**My Code**

```
<b-form @submit.prevent="addReview" name="review-form" novalidate>
  <div class="name">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-input-name">Name</label>
    <b-input id="form-input-name" class="form-inputs mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" v-model="name" placeholder="Name" required :state="isStateValid(this.name)"></b-input>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="form-input-name">
      You must enter a name
    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </div>

  <div class="date">
    <label class="sr-only" for="example-datepicker">Choose a date</label>
    <b-form-datepicker id="datepicker" v-model="dateVisited" class="mb-2" required placeholder="Date Visited" :state="isStateValid(this.dateVisited)"></b-form-datepicker>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="datepicker">
      You must enter a valid date
    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-input-service">Service Provided</label>
    <b-input id="form-input-service" class="form-inputs mb-2" placeholder="Service Provided" v-model="service" required :state="isStateValid(this.service)"></b-input>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="form-input-service">
      You must enter the service provided
    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </div>

  <div class="email">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inline-form-input-username">Email</label>
    <b-input id="inline-form-input-username" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" required :state="emailStateValidation"></b-input>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inline-form-input-username">
      You must enter the part of your email that comes before the '@' symbol
    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </div>

  <div class="domain">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inline-form-input-domain">Domain</label>
    <b-input-group prepend="@" class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
      <b-input id="inline-form-input-domain" placeholder="Domain ex: gmail.com" v-model="domain" required :state="domainStateValidation"></b-input>
      <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inline-form-input-domain">
        You must enter the part of your email that comes after the '@' symbol
      </b-form-invalid-feedback>
    </b-input-group>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <label class="sr-only" for="textarea-rows">Describe Your Experience</label>
    <b-form-textarea class="mb-3 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="textarea-rows" placeholder="Describe Your Experience" rows="4" required v-model="description" :state="isStateValid(this.description)"></b-form-textarea>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="textarea-rows">
      You must enter a description of your experience
    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
  </div>

  <b-button type="submit">Save</b-button>
</b-form>
```

```
computed: {
        emailStateValidation() {
            if (this.email) {
                return this.emailIsValid() ? true : false;
            }
            return null;
        },
        domainStateValidation() {
            if (this.domain) {
                return this.domainIsValid() ? true : false;
            }
            return null;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        emailIsValid() {
            let regEx = /^(?!.*@)((^[^\.])[a-z0-9\.!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~"]*)*([^\.]$)/;
            return regEx.test(this.email);
        },
        domainIsValid() {
            let regEx = /((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return regEx.test(this.domain);
        },
        isStateValid(variable) {
            if (variable) {
                return variable.length > 0 ? true : false;
            }
            return null;
        },
        addReview() {
            let mainForm = document.getElementsByName("review-form")[0];
            mainForm.classList.add("was-validated");
        ...
```

**Questions**

1. Resolve the conflict between required and my custom validation
   causing input fields being prematurely marked as valid
2. Display `b-form-invalid-feedback` on datepicker on form submit if
   date is not selected

Comment: I'm pretty sure both question will be solved when you use `b-form-group` for this

Comment: so you would replace all the ``div's`` with ``b-form-group`` then have the ``:state`` prop on that to display ``b-form-invalid-feedback``?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Here is the [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-tereshkova-mu04b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) focus on the email fields the validation works correctly before the form is submitted however after it is submitted the fields gets marked with a green check marks if any input is entered no matter if it satisfies my custom validation or not. Then datepicker doesn't show any error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, remove `novalidate` from `<form>` in your Vue template. When you set `novalidate`, the inputs will remain in their `:valid` state throughout their lifecycle until you explicitly call `setCustomValidity`. [Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feather-n141d)

Since, Bootstrap styles also apply to `:valid` or `:invalid` states so, even if your custom validators determine inputs to be invalid, both valid and invalid styles will get applied i.e. `:valid` and `.is-invalid` but, I guess it's just happens so, that `:valid` styles take precedence the way Bootstrap stylesheet is currently written.

**U̶s̶e̶ ̶`̶n̶o̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶a̶t̶e̶`̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶l̶e̶t̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶s̶e̶l̶f̶ ̶i̶n̶c̶l̶u̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`̶r̶e̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶d̶`̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶a̶t̶o̶r̶.̶**

**With Bootstrap, since it also applies styles to `:valid` or `:invalid` states of input, you're better off NOT using `novalidate`.**

Ofcourse, this will enable browser popups asking for filling certain fields which might be unwanted.

**Suggestion:** Use `validated` prop on your form and bind it to your form's state and set it to `true` in `addReview()`, it will automatically add `was-validated` class and you don't need to manipulate the DOM directly.

**EDIT:** Since removing `novalidate` enables browser validation, `submit` event no longer fired on the form and hence, `was-validated` class is never added to the form. This presented an issue in my original answer because messages and icon were not shown without `was-validated`. I have modified the sandbox to suggest a fix for that and that is to bind `click` event to submit button for validation logic and using `submit` event for stuff that should happen after successful validation.

**EDIT for Datepicker:** The reason why datepicker never invalidated was because of an issue in `isStateValid()` method specifically the part:

```
if(variable) { // "" evaluates to false
   // ...
}
```

Since `""` evaluates to false, it will always return `null`. The fix for that is in combination with the suggestion above of maintaining `validated` state for the form. Now, instead of checking `if(variable)`, we check `if(this.validated)` and if it is `true`, we simply check the length and return either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Okay so far your answer is the best i have come across and i just need a little time to explore the other answer but do you have any thoughts on getting some error message to display for the datepicker? Is the only option just to check if there is a value saved then display feedback?

Comment: @wcyankees424 Check my edits above and the updated Working Sandbox.

Comment: That is exactly what i have been looking for. Thank You. Ideally I don't want the browser popups but i can deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Fundamentally `was-validated` is not bootstrap-vue native, it's browser native, which also has no understanding of `:state`. If you want to use `was-validated` you can't use custom validations. If you want to use custom validations. See the suggestion For 2. Which is basically, use another variable to control whether validation should be applied.
2. From the documentation on bootstrap-vue

> When set, adds the `aria-required="true"` attribute on the component. Required validation needs to be handled by your application

You need to explicitly check that the validation should show, it isn't clear from the documentation what `required` actually does, but it doesn't affect validation. Which explains why that part isn't working. Personally I set a global `this.showValidations = true` on submit, so that the validations actually run at the right time and not before (and after when expected). In your case, you can check for the `was-validated` class that you are adding explicitly. It isn't great, but it seems it must be done here.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that aria-required is 'only' for accessibility i.e. screen reader etc.

Comment: Sure, but the important part of the quoted text is that the `validation needs to be handled by your application`